# How to fetch data from CSV file in a sequential manner?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, robotframework

I need to have data fetched from a CSV file in the order: R1,C1; R1,C2 till R1,C10 and then R2,C1; R2,C2... using robot framework.

The robotframework script I tried is as follows:

```
 ${File}=    Get File              Text Files\\Book1.csv
    @{list}=    Split to lines  ${File}     
        :FOR    ${line}    IN     @{list}    
         \    Log                             ${line}
         \    ${Value}=   Get Variable Value  ${line}
         \    Input Text    LOCATOR      ${Value}
         \    Press Keys    LOCATOR       RETURN
```

Expected: Script should fetch data in the sequence: R1 - C1,C2,C3....C10; 
                                                    R2 - C1,C2,C3....C10 till last row.

Actual: Script is fetching the data from R1- C1, C2, C3 in single attempt.
The CSV file data is as per the attachment[CSV File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XlcH.jpg):

```
The current script is fetching data as 3 strings : 
Name1Age1Gender1
Name2Age2Gender2
Name3Age3Gender3

But I need to have Name1 in variable <${Value}>, then Age1 in variable ${Value}, then Gender1 in variable ${Value} and use them one-by-one.

Similarly, once it is done with Row1, then it should proceed to Row2 and then Row3.
```

Comment: Can you explain what it is you are having difficulty with?

Comment: What have you tried and what was the observed result?

Comment: Please check above description. I have provided an example and a screenshot.